# hibernate criteria single object load

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, criteria

i have two entity(employeeTo & restTo) there is one-to-many relationship 
 between them,i want to get  employee restTo list only, but when i load the list each of object contain employee object.

employeeTO

```
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employeeTO",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<RestTO> RestTOList=new ArrayList<>();
```

restTO

```
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private EmployeeTO employeeTO;
```

and you can see my code below:

```
  Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(RestTo.class);
criteria.setFetchMode("employeeTO",FetchMode.SELECT);
criteria.createAlias("employeeTO","alians_employee");
Criterion condition1= Restrictions.eq("alians_employee.emID",emid);
criteria.add(condition1);
criteria.add(Restrictions.between("startDate",date1,date2));
List<RestTO> restTOS=criteria.list();
  transaction.commit();
    session.close();
```

> System.out.println(restTOS.get(0).getEmployeeTo.getName);
>   This instruction is  working and show employee name
>
> I want to not have access to employee object

i need load only RestTo object without employeeTo value.
how i can do it?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create an alias,it adss an inner join to your query. So instead of this

```
Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(RestTo.class);
criteria.setFetchMode("employeeTO",FetchMode.SELECT);
criteria.createAlias("employeeTO","alians_employee");
Criterion condition1= Restrictions.eq("alians_employee.emID",emid);
```

Use this

```
Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(RestTo.class);
//Default fetchmode is good,no need for that.
//criteria.setFetchMode("employeeTO",FetchMode.SELECT);
//criteria.createAlias("employeeTO","alians_employee");
Criterion condition1= Restrictions.eq("employeeTO.emID",emid);
```

Comment: thank you very much ,its work for me,im new to hibernate,for this problem , it's better write query on employeeTo and get restTO list or the answer above?

Comment: Query on EmployeeTo will bring parent and child. You only need child(restTo) so the answer aobe is fine.